# Hibernate select query (Employee get by email id or get by name)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my Spring Hibernate project i need single employee object  by there email address not id, From my employee table.

```
 public Employee getEmployeeById(long employeeId) {
        return (Employee) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
        Employee.class, employeeId);
    }
```

Not this one.....!

I need like this :

```
 public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String empEmail) {
        return (Employee) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
        Employee.class, empEmail);
    }
```

But not work.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query class to do that:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String empEmail) {
  Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee where email = :email");
  query.setParameter("email", empEmail);
  return (Employee) query.list().get(0);
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree using HQL, or any plain text string, for querying a database. This makes your code hard to manage, refactor and will bring up the maintenance cost. Similar idea with store procedures. Please see the below Criteria implementation

Answer (score 2):

Using Criteria API:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String empEmail) {
  Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("email", empEmail)); //assuming Employee entity has "email" field
  return (Employee) crit.list().get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use HQL query instead

```
from Employee e where e.email = :empEmail
```

Hibernate [Session#get()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get-java.lang.Class-java.io.Serializable-) with two parameter need to have 2nd parameter of type `Serializable` **id** not any other `Entity` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String empEmail) {
       Employee e = (Employee)
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
       crit.add(Restrictions.eq("email", empEmail)).uniqueResult();
       return e;
    }
```